# Why does my angular directed work on one table cell but none others?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, contextmenu

I am using a [ContextMenu](https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu) directive within a kendo grid.  I have made one change to it so I can include icons in the text (changed $a.text(text) to $a.html(text).

I have one in the first cell (I highjacked the hierarchical cell) that has row operations (add, clone& delete) and one on a span within each cell that changes the cell values operation (addition, subtraction, equals, etc...)

Both of these were working.  I am unsure what I changed that stopped it from working because I last checked it several changes ago (I'm still locked out of TFS so I can't revert).

One change I made was to include a disabled/enabled check to the working contextMenu.  I tried adding the same to the broken one and no dice.

I do perform a $compile on the working menu and the broken one is only included in the kendo field template.

If I must compile the field template (and I didn't need to before), how can this be done?

So here is some code. 
working menu:

```
        $scope.getRowContextMenu = function (event) {

            var options =
            [[
                "<span class='fa fa-files-o'></span>Clone Rule", function (scope, cmEvent) {/*omitted for brevity*/}),rowContextDisableFunction]]
        }

        var setHierarchyCell = function (grid) {
            var element = grid.element;
            var hCells = element.find("td.k-hierarchy-cell");
            hCells.empty();
            var spanStr = "<span context-menu='getRowContextMenu()' class='fa fa-bars'></span>";
            hCells.append($compile(spanStr)($scope));
            var span = hCells.find("span.fa");
            span.on('click', function (event) {
                $(this).trigger('contextmenu', event);
            });
        }
```

kendo template:

```
        var mutliFormTemplate = function (fieldName, type) {
            var result = "";
            result += "<span context-menu='getOperationContextMenuItems()' class='fa #= " + fieldName + "_Obj.OperationSymbol # type-" + type + "'> </span>\n";
           /*The rest pertains to the cell value.  excluded for brevity*/
           return result;
        }

        $scope.getOperationContextMenuItems = function () {
            //I trimmed this all the way down to see if I could get it working.  Still no joy
            return [
                ["test", function () { }, true]
            ];
        }
```

Creating the kendo columns dynamically:

```
        $scope.model = {
            id: "RuleId",
            fields: {}
        };
        $scope.fieldsLoaded = function (data, fields) {

            var column = {}

            $.each(fields, function () {
                var field = this;
                $scope.columns.push({
                    field: field.Name,
                    title: field.Name,
                    template: mutliFormTemplate(field.Name, "selector")
                });
                column[field.Name ] = { type: getFieldType(field.Type.BaseTypeId) }
            });
            $scope.model.fields = column;
      }
```

Thanks for any and all help ^_^